# Regex to match continuous recurrent pattern

Tags: java, regex

Sorry for previous confusion. I have reedited question now.

Can anybody suggest me pattern to match complete recurrent pattern :

for example :

```
 "aabaabaab"  => true // here aab is repeating continuously

 "abcdabcd" => true // here abcd is repeating continuously
```

but

```
"aabbbaadsdsabbba" => false // here no unique pattern is repeating continuously
```

Comment: I can't able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Orion for 3rd one the patterns "aabbb", "aabbba", "aa", "bbb", "ab", etc.  returns true right?

Comment: I tink ` "aabbb", "aabbba"` is a continuos repeat?

Comment: @VamshiAlladi -  No it must not return true  in this  case

Comment: @AvinashRaj - no it is not.  aabbb should only be considered repeatable in following scenario 'aabbbaabbbaabbbaabbbaabbb...'

Comment: I'm asking about `aabbba` not `aabbb`

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
^(.+)\1+$
```

First we capture a group. Then we see whether the group is repeating till the end.
The `\1` denotes the first group captured.

Comment: thanks a lot for this

Comment: @Orion What do you mean? This returns true for the third one https://regex101.com/r/fR1uG7/2

Comment: Sorry... Avinash Raj had already answered the question.

Comment: @Himanshu What do you mean by `already answered the question`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Thanks for helping. I have reedited question to add more clarification.